# VBA auto populates a cell when another cell is populated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 columns in a spreadsheet:

- Column A is an ID (incremented by one for each new record)
- Column B is the name of a City

Is it possible when a new city is added to column B (and only when column B changes) that the ID automatically populates with a value one greater than the previous record.  So for example if I have the current record set:

```
   A    B
   ________
1 | ID  City
2 | 1   London
3 | 2   Paris
4 | 3   New York
```

and I add say Moscow to the list, then value 4 will automatically populate in column A?

```
   A    B
   ________
1 | ID  City
2 | 1   London
3 | 2   Paris
4 | 3   New York
5 | **4**   Moscow
```

It needs to be range based so I can enter as many new records as I need.

I have tried `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange` but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Show us what you've tried first, you probably aren't that far off.

Comment: What exactly did go wrong with selection_change? nothing happens or error pops up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy this into your sheet in vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim xrow As Long

    xrow = 2
    Set KeyCells = Range("B:B")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Do
            If Cells(xrow, 2).Value <> "" Then
                If Cells(xrow, 1).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(xrow, 1).Value = Cells(xrow - 1, 1).Value + 1
                End If
            End If
        xrow = xrow + 1
        Loop Until Cells(xrow, 2) = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

hope I helped :)

Comment: or try : If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Macro it makes just user input data work

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider when implementing a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.

First thing to consider when you plan to change/delete/add any value to the worksheet within the event macro is that you are going to trigger another event and the Worksheet_Change is going to try to run on top of itself. ALWAYS disable event handling with `Application.EnableEvents = False` before changing anything n the worksheet and remember to turn it back on again with `Application.EnableEvents = True` before leaving the event macro or no future event will trigger another Worksheet_Change until event handling is turned back on.

The second thing to consider is how you are going to deal with more than a single cell receiving a change. This could occur if several values were pasted into column B. You also need to isolate the values that were pasted into column B only; other columns could conceivably receive values at the same time.

What to do with the ID if a city value is cleared and checking for duplicates in the city column are other considerations that you should decide on appropriate actions for.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim cty As Range
        For Each cty In Intersect(Target, Columns(2))
            If CBool(Len(cty.Value2)) Then
                cty.Offset(0, -1) = Application.Max(Columns(1)) + 1
                'check for duplicates and mark xlRed if found
                'comment or delete this if not required
                If Application.CountIf(Columns(2), cty.Value2) > 1 Then
                    cty.Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    cty.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                End If
            Else
                'not sure whether you want to clear the
                'ID column if the city column is cleared
                cty.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
                'or clear any background fill from a duplicate
                cty.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        Next cty
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

While I'm using `application.Max` to ensure a unique number, the IDs in column A can be manually edited without any interference from the event macro.

There is a lot that can be done with a Worksheet_Change. The above is pretty good framework to get you started and you should be able to expand on its functionality while 'colouring inside the lines'.